# Angular: Where to put reusable configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just getting started with Angular:

I'd like to create a shared configuration singleton containing, eg the baseURL for service endpoints.

What is the pattern for this in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use something like a constant https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant. This can be injected into any part of your app, even during the config phase.